# How to get conditional sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question about sequence function in SQL Server.

First, I created a base table. Here is my code.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST2(
    SEQ int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    Dates date,
    CNT int,
)
INSERT INTO TEST2 (Dates, CNT)
VALUES 
('2020-01-01', 0),
('2020-01-02', 0),
('2020-01-03', 0),
('2020-01-04', 1),
('2020-01-05', 0),
('2020-01-06', 1),
('2020-01-07', 0),
('2020-01-08', 0),
('2020-01-09', 0),
('2020-01-10', 0),
('2020-01-11', 0),
('2020-01-09', 2),
('2020-01-10', 0),
('2020-01-11', 0)
```

Here my attempt code.

```
CASE WHEN CNT != 0
THEN 0
ELSE CNT = 0
THEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Dates))
END NEW_SEQ
```

It consists of two columns(Dates, CNT).
And I want to get the following result using the WHEN CASE expressions.

Here is my example results.

| SEQ | Dates | CNT | NEW_SEQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 2020-01-03 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 2020-01-04 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 2020-01-05 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 2020-01-06 | 1 | 0 |
| 7 | 2020-01-07 | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | 2020-01-08 | 0 | 2 |
| 9 | 2020-01-09 | 0 | 3 |
| 10 | 2020-01-10 | 0 | 4 |
| 11 | 2020-01-11 | 0 | 5 |
| 12 | 2020-01-09 | 2 | 0 |
| 13 | 2020-01-10 | 0 | 1 |
| 14 | 2020-01-11 | 0 | 2 |

I want to get like this using CASE WHEN Method.
Please check my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Please also explain the logic required for the `NEW_SEQ`

Comment: Also, `NEW_SEQ` against `'2020-01-01'` should be 0

Comment: Also `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: @DaleK I edited my text.

Comment: That syntax doesn't run though?

Comment: @DaleK It's too difficult, but I'll try one more.

Comment: `else` doesn't have a condition nor a `then`

Comment: BTW good work on creating the DDL+DML, although you don't need that for your expected results, only the sample data. I have updated your question. This is a good template for the future.

Comment: @DaleK I'm really appreciate your advice. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
select t.Dates, t.CNT, 
       row_number() over (partition by sm order by seq) - 1 as NEW_SEQ
from
(select t.*,
       sum(case when cnt = 0 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by seq) as sm
  from test t) t
```